# Not able to make mqtt call in browser

Tags: aws-iot

I am using below plugin to make **mqtt** call

aws-iot-device-sdk-browser

On trying to set protocol **mqtt** or **mqtts**, it is failing to connect saying as invalid options.
If we set protocol to wss, it is connecting to with out aws  certificates.

To keep it secure need to pass cert files.

Can i make mqtt call from browser or wss call with making sure to accept cert files

```
awsIot.device({
      clientId: clientId,
      accessKeyId: accessKeyId,
      //privateKey: privateKey,
      //clientCert: clientCert,
      //caCert: caCert,
      secretKey: secretKey,
      region: region,
      baseReconnectTimeMs: 3000,
      poty: port,
      protocol: 'wss',
      host: host,
      debug: true
    });
```

Can anyone please help to make **mqtt** call or make secure connection from **wss** using **aws-iot-device-sdk-browser** is secure with cert files

Comment: You shouldn't use the certs from the browser, as soon as you share them in a browser anyone can copy them to connect from anywhere including the sdk. [Here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-mqtt) is an example that is easy to use with cognito auth. That has both an unauth and auth capability.

Comment: You should use signed websocket url to achive this, For this you will need a backend service or lamda, etc to create a valid url with sigv4 for browser clients to fetch, then use this url to start some javascript mqtt client to connect aws iot assets.